# How to create a non-empty comment node using `h`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-render-function

The following code will produce an empty comment node i.e. `<!---->`.
How to produce a non-empty comment node e.g. `<!-- Foo -->` using `h`?

```js
export default {
  render(h) {
    return h(null)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Vue 2.6.14 no longer allows doing any of the following, but it's possible in Vue 3.

#### Option 1: `h(null)` with string as second argument

```js
import { h } from 'vue' //  Vue 3

export default {
  render() {
    return h(null, 'This is a comment')  // <!--This is a comment-->
  },
}
```

**Note:** This generates a runtime warning about using `null`:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: null

You could workaround that with `resolveDynamicComponent(null)` instead of `null`:

```js
import { h, resolveDynamicComponent } from 'vue' // Vue 3

export default {
  render() {
    return h(resolveDynamicComponent(null), 'This is a comment')  // <!--This is a comment-->
  },
}
```

#### Option 2: `h(Comment)` with string as second argument

```js
import { h, Comment } from 'vue' // Vue 3

export default {
  render() {
    return h(Comment, 'This is a comment')  // <!--This is a comment-->
  },
}
```

#### Option 3: `createCommentVNode()` with string as argument

```js
import { createCommentVNode } from 'vue' // Vue 3

export default {
  render() {
    return createCommentVNode('This is a comment')  // <!--This is a comment-->
  },
}
```

**Note**: `createCommentVNode` is an internal API, which can be removed/renamed in a future release, so use it with caution.

[Vue 3 demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-create-comment-nodes?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: @user1620220 Thanks for the heads up. It seems Vue 2 no longer allows creating comment nodes. Updated answer.